# How to have different border size between multiple div related to text size?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i need to do that for the UI of my game.
I need to go from this :
[image: Current situation]

To this (its an editing with paint.net of the previous picture) :
[image: Desired result]

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hud">
            <div style="border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);">&nbsp;<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jElAfE.png"/>&nbsp;0&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);">&nbsp;<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jElAfE.png"/>&nbsp;100 500 000000&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);">&nbsp;LSPD - Cadet de la police trop cool&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#hud {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Pricedown';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    text-align: center;
    top: 35px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your inner `div`s takes `100%` of parent's `width`. Can You try with `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: judging from your images, I think you mean *width* , not border size as stated in your header (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flexbox` with `margin-left: auto;` and don't style your elements on the tags like that, it's considered bad practice and you're honestly just making it harder on yourself in the long run.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hud">
            <div>&nbsp;<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jElAfE.png"/>&nbsp;0&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jElAfE.png"/>&nbsp;100 500 000000&nbsp; 
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;LSPD - Cadet de la police trop cool&nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#hud {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Pricedown';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  top: 35px;
  right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#hud > div{
  background-color:red;
  border: 2px solid #000; 
  border-radius: 3px; 
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);
  margin: 2px 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/poojagv)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap every inner `div` inside another one and make all inner `divs` as `display: inline-block;`

[Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ykav1uh/2/)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="hud">
            <div><div style="border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);">&nbsp;<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jElAfE.png"/>&nbsp;0&nbsp;</div></div>
            <div><div style="border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);">&nbsp;<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7jElAfE.png"/>&nbsp;100 500 000000&nbsp;</div></div>
            <div><div style="border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.40);">&nbsp;LSPD - Cadet de la police trop cool&nbsp;</div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#hud div div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Of course to organize code better, set up `CSS` classes for inner `div`s and create proper `CSS` for them.